# pass relation in a function argument (sequel)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a rails project that I am using the `sequel gem` (ORM). I would like to understand if is it possible to pass the relation in a function argument.

Something like this (This solution doesn't work):

```
def query(relation)
  Album.eager(relation)
end

query(artist: label)
query(:artist)
query(:artist, :tracks)
```

Documentation:
http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/Associations/DatasetMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with how argument are passed in Ruby. If you accept one argument you can't call it with *N*. Fix is this:

```
def query(*relations)
  Album.eager(*relations)
end
```

Where now you accept zero or more arguments and pass them through as-is using the *splat operator*.

Comment: yes, but I got this error: undefined local variable or method `label' for main:Object (NameError)